# Swift How to use single guard let statement for multiple UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Hello All I am currently having issues tryin to use one guard let for a couple of textfield instaed of multiple guard let for each textfield and an UIAlertController if any textfield is empty. This is the code I tried below. But the alert controller is not being called. Can someone please advise me what am doing wrong

```
    @IBAction func submitBankInfo(_ textField: UITextField) {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
       guard let accountOwner = accountOwnerTxt.text, accountOwner !   
         = "", let accountNumber = accountNumberTxt.text, accountNumber !
       = "", let bvn = bvnTxt.text, bvn != "", let bankName = 
      nameOfBankTxt.text, bankName != "" else {
        if textField.text == nil {
            switch textField {
            case accountNumberTxt:
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self.showAlert(title: "Error!", message: "Account is required.Please enter your number")
                }
            case bvnTxt:
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self.showAlert(title: "Error!", message: "BVN is required.Please enter your bank verification number(BVN)")
                }
            case nameOfBankTxt:
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self.showAlert(title: "Error!", message: "Bank name     required.Please enter your bank name")
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        return
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working" (please, never use that term. Be clear, concise, and specific). [Edit] your question to make it clear.

Comment: @codeperfect What is the error in logs ??

Comment: `!=` separated by a new line character looks weird. There is a simpler syntax : `!accountOwner.isEmpty`

Comment: @maddy, I have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @vadian, there is really no error. The alertcontroller is not being called when the texfield is empty

Comment: @codeperfect can you put a breakpoint and check what is actually happening? Or check this-: https://medium.com/practical-ios-development/how-to-combine-multiple-guard-statements-in-swift-a22c5a9512a5

Comment: Of course it's not called if the text field is empty because you are checking only for `nil`. In this case I would separate the `guard` expressions.

Comment: Also note that this doesn't do what you probably want.  It's going to display an error message relevant to the field passed in, NOT relevant to the field actually in error.  Split it up into multiple guards, one per field and eliminate the confusing switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an embedded function to generalize the validation and keep your guard statement focused on the valid scenario.

```
@IBAction func submitBankInfo(_ textField: UITextField) 
{
   self.view.endEditing(true)

   func validField(_ field:UITextField, _ message:String) -> String?
   { 
      if let fieldValue = field.text, fieldValue != ""
      { return fieldValue }
      OperationQueue.main.addOperation 
      { self.showAlert(title: "Error!", message: message) }
      return nil 
   }

   guard let accountOwner  = validField(accountOwnerTxt, "Account owner is required.Please enter your identification"),
         let accountNumber = validField(accountNumberTxt,"Account is required.Please enter your number"),
         let bvn           = validField(bvnTxt,          "BVN is required.Please enter your bank verification number(BVN)"),
         let bankName      = validField(nameOfBankTxt,   "Bank name required.Please enter your bank name")
   else  { return }

   // proceed with valid data ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func unwrapValues() -> Bool {
    guard let email = self.txtEmail.text, email != "", let phone = self.txtPhone.text, phone != "", let password = self.txtPassword.text, password != "" else {
        //show your error here
        return false
    }
    
    // here you will get unwrapped values of email, phone & password
    return true
}
```